# Imported model from Blender stops updating after applying scripts

Tags: unity, models, blender, scripting, import

I am new to Unity3D and I am trying to import a model from Blender. I save the .blend file inside the assets folder and everything works well. I drag and drop my model and apply textures, colliders and insert a player. Up until that point, I am able to change things in Blender, and see the changes inside Unity. But my problem begins when I try to apply scripts in my objects. Then the connection between Blender and Unity breaks and the model is not updated in the later.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you mean by "apply scripts"? Where do you apply them? What is not updating, mesh?, materials?, textures? Is it a prefab? Some screen-shots may prove useful.

Comment: When exporting objects from a 3D software, Unity only takes needed data like meshes. When you use these in Unity, you have to create a `GameObject` with the imported object's `Mesh` and any scripts you attach to it. If you update the `Mesh` file (in this case `.blender` file) then the `GameObject` should update its appearance automatically and keep all its scripts. Where exactly are you encountering this error?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that the scripts are compiling and not throwing an error. This can stop Unity's blender import from working.
2. Try exporting to fbx instead. It is what Unity recommends in their art asset guide - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ArtAssetBestPracticeGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I never use Blender. But I'd suggest using a .OBJ file instead. And when you edit, edit the .obj version. .obj is something unity should natively support so i use it a lot.